# Why do these 2 alerts show different values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I restart from begining.

My intranet webpage works like this:

1) User load the page, I load my motor database with $.Post in an array named motorsFull.

```
// load from my motor database 
$.post("ajax.php?action=chargementBases",
    function(data) {
    motorsFull = data[0];
},"json");

// array built in ajax.php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM details_moteurs ORDER BY m_update_id DESC");
    $i=0;
    while ($infosMoteurs = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $arrayMoteur[$i] = $infosMoteurs;
        $i++;
}
```

2) when user type in a research field I filter my array motorsFull and copy from it the lines matching the keywords with a function.

3) Every line of my motor database is an update, so you can have 3..10..25 entry for one motor id. This allow me to save all the change done by all users.

4) When a search is done, after filtering my motorsFull array I return the 10 first lines under motorsToDisplay array to my display update function.

5) To get the last value displayed on the user screen, for the 10 first motors returned I look for updates in my motorsFull array and update each cell of motorsToDisplay depending on some parameters with the following code. (All the code is not there only the update of the data for each different motor found).

```
for (var k=0; k < motorsFull.length;k++ )
{
    //si on est sur le même moteur et que le n° d'update est différent
    if(motorsToDisplay[i]['m_id'] == motorsFull[k]['m_id'] && motorsToDisplay[i]['m_update_id'] != motorsFull[k]['m_update_id']){

        //historique k plus ancien que i
        if(motorsFull[k]['m_last_update'] > motorsToDisplay[i]['m_last_update']){

            // pour chaque case de la ligne en cours
            for (var positionDansLigne in motorsToDisplay[i]){

                //si la case récente est  vide
                if(motorsFull[i][positionDansLigne] == '')
                {
                    // si la case ancienne n'est pas vide
                    if(motorsFull[k][positionDansLigne] == ''){

                        if(positionDansLigne != 'm_update_id' && positionDansLigne != 'm_user_done_update'&& positionDansLigne != 'm_update_type'&& positionDansLigne != 'm_update_comment'&& positionDansLigne != 'm_id'&& positionDansLigne != 'm_last_update'){

                            //on ecrase la valeur vide par l'ancien historique
                            motorsToDisplay[i][positionDansLigne] = motorsFull[k][positionDansLigne];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else{

            //historique k plus récent que i
            // pour chaque case de la ligne en cours

            for (var positionDansLigne in motorsToDisplay[i]){

                // si la case du tableau plus récent n'est pas vide
                if(motorsToDisplay[k][positionDansLigne] != ''){

                    if(positionDansLigne != 'm_update_id' && positionDansLigne != 'm_user_done_update'&& positionDansLigne != 'm_update_type'&& positionDansLigne != 'm_update_comment'&& positionDansLigne != 'm_id'&& positionDansLigne != 'm_last_update'){

                        //on ecrase la valeur par le nouvel historique
                        motorsToDisplay[i][positionDansLigne] = motorsFull[k][positionDansLigne];   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

6) My problem start here. I dont know why but the first time I read my motorsFull everthing is okay, but after I readed it the data are updated like I done in my array motorsToDisplay with the function above. Nowhere in my code I update any value from motorsFull.

6b) I wrote following code to display you the content of my array motorsFull for a specific motor after and before it was read.

```
var textDebug ='';
    for (var k=0; k < motorsFull.length;k++ )
    {
        if(motorsFull[k]['m_id']=='507'){
            textDebug+='\r\r Line '+k+': ';
            for (var y in motorsFull[k]){
                textDebug+='['+ motorsFull[k][y]+'] ';
            }
        }
    }
    alert(textDebug);
```

7) If anyone could explain me why I dont read the same data twice from motorsFull, or why this array is updated it could help me. I can also provide the complete code but it is over 1000 lines :-)

**Before**

[image: Before]

===================================================

**After**

[image: After]

**Hint:**  If this line is commented my motorsFull dosen't change.

```
motorsToDisplay[i][positionDansLigne] = motorsFull[k][positionDansLigne];
```

**EDIT: Here is my complete code (without ajax.php)**

http://www.mediafire.com/view/dc48wv0voiqnuuw/fonctionsMoteurs.js
http://www.mediafire.com/view/j4uj4daztfyzai5/moteurs.php

Comment: When do you call `xyz()`: after or before the `$.post()` request is made?

Comment: After. When the document is fully loaded it create the Html element who trigger the function.

Comment: Do you initialize `arrayMoteursFull` on the global level? Because if not, they are 2 different vars with their own scope in each of those pieces of code. Also, you may have a timing issue, depending on when `xyz()` is called vs. that ajax request

Comment: Isint a variable always global when you dont use VAR myVariable ?

Comment: What triggers the `$.post()` call, then? And are you aware that `myFunction xyz(){` is not valid code?

Comment: $.post() is triggered by a document.ready function. and yes function myFunction xyz() :)

Comment: There's an `i` variable being used there, how are you updating that?

Comment: This [i] variable is updated in my main loop which read all the matching line of motorsToDisplay and update/display the first then and only count the ones > 10.

Comment: Added a link to complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't read the mediafire code (says "loading" indefinitely, and I've no idea whether I need an account or what else), but --

You have a non-trivial data structure (arrays of dictionaries), for which I did not see the initialization: I suspect that when populating `motorsToDisplay` and `motorsToDisplay` you at some time put the same dictionary into both.

Changing a dictionary by saying `dict['key'] = value` will change the dictionary, i.e., the change will of course change the dictionary, which when used two times, shows the change in two places.

Please check whether you can find a

```
motorsToDisplay[i] = motorsFull[k];
```

or a

```
dict = { ... };
motorsToDisplay[i] = dict; 
motorsFull[k] = dict;
```

somewhere...

Comment: I did not understand everything in your post but, i got motorsToDisplay[i] = motorsFull[k]; in my code.

Comment: Well, there you go: The thing that is in `motorsFull[k]` is put into `motorsToDisplay` (at some array position). This is not a problem with atomic values (such as `Number`s or `String`s), because they can't change. But when you use a complex value, such as a dictionary, you may later change the dictionaries content, without changing the dictionaries identity. Think of it as a cardboard box: You have put the same box into both arrays. Now you put something into the box by writing `motorsToDisplay[i]['key'] = 42'...

Comment: ... This changes the contents of the box, but this same box is still reachable from the other array -- `motorsFull[i]['key']` is now 42. (The same applies to arrays, by the way.) What you need to do if you want them to be different, is to create a copy of the dictionary: I found http://scriptcult.com/subcategory_1/article_414-copy-or-clone-javascript-array-object, for one example. Does that make it clear?

Comment: Understood, but I initialized my array arrayFiltered (motorsToDisplay) with var arrayFiltered = new Array(); , why isint a new array object created then?

Comment: The issue is not the array `motorsToDisplay`, but the things inside that array. How do you add items to that array?

Comment: arrayFiltered[nbrResultsFiltered] = motorsFull[j];

Comment: Schould i use then something like arrayFiltered[nbrResultsFiltered] = new Array(motorsFull[j]); and checking the source thing?

Comment: Nop still having the same problem :S

Comment: OK solved it with your link and function function cloneObject(source) {
    for (i in source) {
        if (typeof source[i] == 'source') {
            this[i] = new cloneObject(source[i]);
        }
        else{
            this[i] = source[i];
  }
    }
}